# Not seeing an etc folder on my Ubuntu Server

Tags: unix, ubuntu, amazon-web-services

I've got an ASW Host running Ubuntu and I don't see an `etc` folder such as what is referenced in [these docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/QuickStartEC2Instance.html).

Why is that?
I also don't see a `/usr/local/bin` folder

When I do an ls -a I get:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably in /home/ubuntu.

Type

> sudo ls -a /etc

Comment: thanks I'm a newbie to Unix.

Comment: Actually, the first command is unnecessary if you use an absolute pathname.

Comment: @StephenC - Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your currently in your home folder. You need to do `ls -l /` or first `cd /` and than `ls -l`. The /-folder is the root folder of a Linux system.

More information: [Linux file system structure](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/linux-file-system-structure/)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking in your HOME directory.

Try to look in `/etc` !